# Qt Creator: Multi line text editing - Linux

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, ide, qt-creator

How can one enable or use multi line editing in Qt Creator under Linux?

I know it from Windows to be shift+alt+up/down to get multiple cursors. Now on Linux, I can only use shift+alt+down to copy or paste columns of multiple lines, but i don't get multiple cursors to edit directly.
Shift+alt+up triggers an (probably) Ubuntu specific tab view, so that i can't use it. I also can't seem to find that shortcut in the shortcut menu to disable it. =(

My Linux Distribution is ubuntu 12.04 LTS
and Qt Creator is version 3.0.1

Comment: I found a Solution to the embedded Question about disabling Shift+Alt+Up shortcut on Ubuntu here:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/171489/how-to-unbind-shift-alt-up-shortkey-in-12-04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column editing feature was introduced in Qt Creator 3.2 (https://www.qt.io/blog/2014/08/19/qt-creator-3-2-0-released). So an update should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, I could have thought of that.